# expand accordion/link at bottom of ul li list

Tags: php, css, accordion, html-lists

I have a bullet list as below:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  text1 here    
 </li>
 <li>
  text2 here    
 </li>
 <li>
  text3 here        
 </li>
 <li>
  text4 here        
 </li>
 <li>
  text5 here        
 </li>
 <li>
  text6 here        
 </li>
 <li>
  text7 here        
 </li>
</ul>
```

I only show the f1rst 3 bullets, but have a link at the bottom to show the rest if clicked (an accordion type effect). Ideally I would also have a close link to compress it again after it had been expanded.

What is the best way to do this with PHP & can I do this just with CSS?

Thanks

Comment: What script are you using for the accordion? Probably has the method to hide, just attach the respective handler

Comment: Actually it can be done with CSS if you use the `:target` selector, but only in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group link which you want to be hidden in 
Ex.

```
<li>Text 1</li>
<li>Text 2</li>
<li>Text 3</li>
<li class="hidden">
 <ul>
  <li>Text 4</li>
  <li>Text 5</li>
  <li>Text 6</li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

And use jQuery to attach accordion to it

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('a#trigger').click(function() {
        $('li ul.hidden').next().toggle('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Of course you have to give display: none; to .hidden class
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't believe that PHP is really the answer you want here.  This feels like something better suited for the front-end.  Take a look at [Google results for 'javascript accordion'](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+accordion) that will detail how you can best do this.

---

That being said you could do this with strictly CSS, however it is CSS3 and might not be widely supported yet.  Could check out [this tutorial/article](http://webdesignernotebook.com/css/the-css3-target-pseudo-class-and-css-animations/) about the `:target` pseudo-class.

You **could** do this in PHP and CSS by setting up your script to respond to a URL parameter that toggles an active/inactive class on the menu fragments you want to hide or show.  Then its a simple matter of writing the CSS rules to show/hide based on the class.  However keep in mind that this might mean a round trip to your server and back just to collapse a menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can quite easily do it with JS.

First change your base HTML to look like

```
<ul>
 <li id="myli1">
  text1 here    
 </li>
 <li id="myli2">
  text2 here    
 </li>
 <li id="myli3">
  text3 here        
 </li>
 <li id="myli4" style="display:none;">
  text4 here        
 </li>
 <li id="myli5" style="display:none;">
  text5 here        
 </li>
 <li id="myli6" style="display:none;">
  text6 here        
 </li>
 <li id="myli7" style="display:none;">
  text7 here        
 </li>
</ul>
```

Then include a function like

```
function ShowMyLi(fromnr,displaystyle) {
  var o=document.getElementById("myli"+fromnr);
  if (!o) return;
  o.style.display="block";
  var cmd="ShowMyLi("+(fromnr+1).toString()+",'"+displaystyle+"');";
  window.setTimeout(cmd,150);
}
```

- On the "show more" button do `onclick="ShowMyLi(4,'block');"`
- On the "hide more" button do `onclick="ShowMyLi(4,'none');"`

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a Server-side language what you're looking for is a client-side solution. Mootools has a [Slide](http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Fx.Slide) function which you could use very easily or you could try a JQuery solution [Here's a list](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-accordion-menus-tutorials/) have fun :)